# how to prevent location object to reset on reload reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Link to re-direct call another component. Something like this

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/app/" + app.appId, appDetail: { app: app } }}>>
```

On calling path /app/:appId It calls AppDetails Component. And I'm getting appDetail object in location object.

But on reloading the route /app/:appId this appDetail in location object is becoming undefined. So How can I prevent this so that on reloading /app/:appId this appDetail from the location object  should not get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `state` property to pass data to other component. So you can do something like this:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: "/app/" + app.appId,
  state: { appDetail: { app: app }}
}}>
```

And get `appDetail` in other component:

```
const { appDetail } = this.props.location.state;
```

Comment: I was using localStorage that is also working. But this is the solution to use state in Link

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways you can control this behavior here is one:
try putting location object in if condition like:

```
if(!location) {
  return <>Loading...</>
}
```

this above condition will hold execution till condition meets